# SharedPreference Flutter Not Updating Realtime

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

New to flutter, trying out shared preference. I select an item, sharedPreference doesn't show selected item unless I close and open the app... So, it's saved but doesn't update realtime.

**SHAREDPREFERENCE**

```
static String selectedLanguageKey = "language";
static SharedPreferences? _prefs;

static Future<SharedPreferences?> init() async {
  _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return _prefs;
 }

static String? getSelectedLanguage() {
  return _prefs?.getString(selectedLanguageKey);
}
```

**HOME**

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

String? _selectedLanguage;

void getSelectedLanguage() {
setState(()  {
  _selectedLanguage = 
LocalPreference.getSelectedLanguage();
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
getSelectedLanguage();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  .........

   //there is a widget here that when tapped shows a modalbottomsheet where user selects a language

  onTap: () {
           
        showModalBottomSheet() 
     }
  

 //now here I display the current selected language, but it doesn't update real time. Only when I close and open app
   Text(
     _selectedLanguage?? Strings.hindi,
   
  }

 }
```

Comment: Your code format is broken, can you reformat it . also the to call method use `()` inside function like `showModalBottomSheet ()`

Comment: Yes, that part wasn't necessary thats why I left it.. Will update

Comment: try `async{
     await showModalBottomSheet();
    setState((){);`